# Passing dynamic variables to Rails controller through an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am working on a rails app and I want to create a dynamical amount of variables to pass to my controller via an AJAX request. That is, I want to create 3 variables if there are only 3 objects and 5 variables if there are 5 objects.

In my javascript file, I've already managed to create a dynamic amount of variables.

```
var count = parseInt("#{@matches.count}");

while(count>0){
  eval("result_" + count + "= $('input:radio[name=result_" + count + "]:checked').val()");
  count -= 1;
}
```

This creates `result_1`, `result_2`, `result_3`, etc.

The AJAX request I have so far is static in that it always has to have 5 results. I want this to be dynamic.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/mt_results/create',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    'result_1' : { matched_id: "#{@matches.first.id}", result: result_1 },                                             
    'result_2' : { matched_id: "#{@matches.second.id}", result: result_2 },
    'result_3' : { matched_id: "#{@matches.third.id}", result: result_3 },
    'result_4' : { matched_id: "#{@matches.fourth.id}", result: result_4 },
    'result_5' : { matched_id: "#{@matches.fifth.id}", result: result_5 }
  },
  success: function(e){
    console.log("AWWWWWWW YEAH!!");
  }
});
```

Is the best way to approach this to dynamically create the JSON object (similar to how I created `results_#`) and assign it to a variable (let's call it `data_var`). Then, I can just pass data_var like below:

```
data: data_var
```

Any tip or feedback on how I can improve my code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using inline Ruby and then AJAX? Seems contradictory...

Comment: I think your proposed solution to dynamically created the data is fine.

Comment: @elclanrs Still relatively new to webdev so I don't understand a lot of the nuances. Is this typically not the way to approach it? The view for this code is the new method and I make an AJAX call to the create method to pass in data and create objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, when you write JS, you should not use inline ruby unless absolutely necessary. Most of the times, it's a sign of bad design and produces code that is tightly coupled to your server-side logic.

It's better to store the data you need in your tag attributes - or use those that already exist.

in your case, you could do :

```
<% @matches.each do |match| %>
   <%= check_box_tag :my_button_group, false, value: match.id %>
<% end %>
```

*(btw, you should not use radio buttons when you allow multiple choices - use checkboxes)*

if you really need to add more data, you can do it the html5 way by adding this to the options :

```
data: {custom-value: "foo", another-one: "bar"},
```

which would add these attributes to the tag :

```
<input ... data-custom-value="foo" data-another-one="bar" />
```

Now - you want to analyze these boxes and send an ajax request to whatever. Why even bothering analysis ? Rails gives you a simple way to handle remote forms. Just wrap your boxes in a remote form, submit it on click, and there you go - it even degrades gracefully !

If you have something more difficult to perform (with data-attributes...), crafting yourself the ajax call data is always possible :

```
var boxes = $("input:checkbox[name=my_button_group]:checked");
var data  = boxes.map(function(box, index){ 
                return { matched_id: box.val(), result: box.attr("data-custom") };
            });
```